# regular expression match dates in strings containing: special characters, digits, letters

Tags: c++, regex

I have the following regular expression to extract the date patterns:

- `^\d{1,2}[-/. ]\d{1,2}[-/. ]\d{1,4}$`

This regular expression matches the following dates: *11/10/2004, 19/20/1999* etc.
But it doesn't match patterns where i have special characters: ***aa(11/10/2004);,***

How can i modify it to match a date even when it contains other "letters, characters digits"

---

I removed the anchor parts and still couldn't match the date.
not match: 26/11/2004), 25/10/2003),

---

C++:

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string d = "25/10/2003),";
    const boost::regex e("\\d{1,2}[-/. ]\d{1,2}[-/. ]\\d{1,4}");
    bool x = boost::regex_match(d,e);
    if(x)
    {
        cout <<"found date" << endl;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: In `aa(11/10/2004);,`, would want to match the whole string or just the `11/10/2004` part?

Comment: I want to match the `11/10/2004` part. To make it simpler I just want to know if a string contains a date pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply remove the characters that anchor the match to the start and end of the string `^$`:

`^.*\d{1,2}[-/. ]\d{1,2}[-/. ]\d{1,4}.*$`

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/hJ9gV4)</kbd>

Comment: @sshanhank I have a problem i'll show it in my question.

Comment: yes it worked. I was thiking about it. so `.*` means any character before and after right?

Comment: @HaniGoc, Sort of. `.*` will match anything except newlines

Comment: Why be simple (i.e. `regex_search`) and use the tool designed for the job, when you can be complicated, and twist another tool to work?  (Which sounds a lot harsher than I mean it; I'll often use something like this too, especially when trying to match several subpatterns.)

Answer (score 1):

Your using the wrong function.  `regex_match` is to determine
whether a given regular expression completely matches a string.
What you want is `regex_search`, which searches for a matching
sequence anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me.

```
regex regExDate("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}");
string date = "abc:\\2016-09-12";
smatch match;

if (regex_search(date, match, regExDate))
{
 string strDate = match.str();
}
```